# PHP & MySQL: unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Getting unexpected T_VARIABLE on 18 which is - **while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetchCourses)) {**

```
<?php include("config.php"); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/reset.css" type="text/css" media=screen />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media=screen />
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$fetchCourses = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM CourseMembers
                            LEFT JOIN Courses ON Courses.CourseID = CourseMembers.CourseID
                            WHERE CourseMembers.UserID = 1
                            ORDER BY Courses.CourseName ASC")

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetchCourses)) {
    echo $row['CourseName'];
} ?>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Missing ';' in the previous line.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, missing the semi colon on the line with the mysql_query.